# Finding the stable period $4$ orbit of a trajectory

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I am told to find the stable period $4$ orbit of $f(x) = 13xe^{-x}$ for my discrete dynamical system through direct numerical iteration. However, I am a bit confused on what is meant by direct numerical iteration.

Usually I can just find $x$ such that $f^{(2)}(x)=x$, but for this function that is quite complicated to do. So how can I find the period $4$ equilibrium points through numerical iteration? I can plot $f$ and $y=x$ together and then vary $x$ and look at the cobweb diagram, but I don't think that is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $x$ is a stable equilibrium point for $f^4$, what happens if you choose $y$ (hopefully reasonably close to $x$) and compute 
$$y, \, f^4(y),  \, f^8(y),  \, f^{12}(y),  \, f^{16}(y), ...
$$
???

**Followup:** Let me expand my hint.

This is experimental mathematics: you pick values; you make guesses; you compute; you look for patterns; you try to prove your patterns.

Pick some starting value of $y$. Any value. Let's pick $y=1$. To remember that it is a starting value, let's put a subscript on it: $y_0=1$.

Now let's start computing. Mathematica might be useful. But, not having it at my fingertips, I searched for a web calculator, and settled on http://web2.0calc.com
$$f(y_0) = f(1) = 13 \times 1 \times e^{-1} \approx 4.7824
$$
$$f^2(y_0) \approx f(4.7824) = 13 \times 4.7824 \times e^{-4.7824} \approx .52072457
$$
$$f^3(y_0) \approx f(.5207245) = 13 \times .52072457 \times e^{-.52072457} \approx 4.0216418
$$
$$f^4(y_0) \approx f(4.0216418) = 13 \times 4.0216418 \times e^{-4.0216418} \approx .937065
$$
That's your first iteration, let's call it $y_1$:
$$y_1 \approx .937065
$$
Now on to your second iteration: 
$$f(y_1) \approx 4.772554
$$
$$f^2(y_1) \approx f(4.772554) \approx .524807
$$
$$f^3(y_1) \approx f(.524807) \approx 4.036660
$$
$$f^4(y_1) \approx f(4.036660) \approx 0.926544
$$
And that's your second iteration, let's call it $y_2$:
$$y_2 \approx 0.926544
$$
So far, we have computed the first three terms of a sequence $y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,...$ the totality of which is defined by recursion: $y_0=1$, $y_{n+1} = f^4(y_n)$ for all $n \ge 0$.

So far there's not too much of a pattern, other than $y_0 > y_1 > y_2$. But  that's not bad actually, because a decreasing sequence of positive numbers must converge. Of course, you don't know for sure yet whether the entire infinite sequence is decreasing.

Shall we try to prove rigorously, perhaps by an induction argument that the sequence must decrease? Shall we compute a few more terms to get a better feel for the pattern? Shall we decide that our first pick $y_0=1$ was not very helpful and try another pick? Only time will tell...

Comment: If I choose a point close to $x$, a stable equilibrium point for $f^{(4)}$, and then look at the trajectory plot of $f^{(4)}$ I should see a stable plot. I think I should see 4 straight lines then. I'm not actually sure what a stable plot looks like for a period-$n$ plot ($n>1$).

Comment: I didn't say plot. I said compute. Use a calculator.

Comment: I don't understand. How am I supposed to compute anything if I don't know what $x$ actually is. Without knowing that I won't know what $y$ to choose. The computaitons should converge to some value assuming $y$ was picked close enough to $x$.

Comment: Choose multiple starting points. Just to be sure :)

Comment: @Evgeny How do we know what starting points, $y$, to pick if we don't know what $x$ is?

Comment: For heaven's sake! Just pick a starting point already! Use your birthday! Use your mother's shoe size! Just get on with it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am trying to figure out how to use mathematica to find the values of $f^{4}(y), f^{8}(y), $etc but i'm not sure how to make NestList[] iterate my function by $4$ each time. Additionally, comments like that are not helpful for someone new to the material.

Comment: If you have a question about coding, that's for another website. But you weren't asking about that – you were asking about how to pick $y$. I'm sorry if you found my suggestions less than helpful.

Comment: @Taln Of course we don't know what $x$ is. But since we are looking  for stable fixed point, we can get a feeling where it might be by picking many starting points, iterating them long enough (since we are trying to find object that is characteristic for long-term behaviour) and looking where do they accumulate.

Comment: @Evgeny $1$ seems to be an equilibrium point, but how do we know that there aren't more? I'm using this code: `f[x_] := 13 x E^-x
bit        = Nest[f, 1, #] & /@ Prepend[1]@Range[4, 16, 4]

ListPlot[bit, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Joined -> True  ] `

Comment: @Taln I'm not using Mathematica, so I can't say whether this code is valid or not. I might say that if you want to find fixed or periodic points for this mapping, you can find many of them in $\lbrack 0, \max\limits_{x\geqslant 0} f(x) \rbrack$ segment (it's invariant for this mapping). If you want to know everything about other periodic points rigorously, there is a wonderful world of one-dimensional dynamics :) it's not my specialization, so I can't say more.